# Не удается установить ubuntu рядом с win10. UEFI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, установка, gparted

Устанавливаю с флешки `Windows` в boot-меню выбираю `UEFI:имя флешки`. Флешку сделал загрузочной через `rufus` для `UEFI` с разметкой `GPT`. Windows ставится нормально с разметкой `GPT`(проверил через `diskpart` и в `Управление дисками`). После установки `windows` пытаюсь установить `ubuntu 18.04`. Загружаюсь с `liveCD` также в boot-меню выбираю `UEFI:имя флешки`, после чего захожу в `gparted` для того, чтобы создать разделы для `ubuntu`. Тут выскакивает ошибка - `“The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.”` и после того как я создаю разделы - все нафиг форматируется, после применения изменений на моменте создания linux-swap. Ошибка выскакивает в любом случае, даже если я еще не установил `windows` и у меня диск полностью unallocated и в этом случае после этой ошибки я пытался создать таблицу разделов `GPT` через `gparted` device->create partition table, при создании вылетает - `“The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.”`.

Как я совершал установку убунту рядом с `windows`:
Создаваю один раздел и устанавливаю на него `windows`, далее "отрезаю" немного памяти для `linux-swap` и для `ext4`(где будет стоять сама ubuntu). После я применяю изменения и выскакивает ошибка - `libparted messages - /dev/sda: unrecognized disk lable` на моменте создания `linux-swap`, после этого как закрываю окно, выскакивает снова сообщение - `“The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.”`, можно нажать `OK` либо `Cancel`, чтобы я не выбрал - диск форматируется и становится весь unallocated и я ничего не могу дальше с ним сделать, т.к. когда пытаюсь создать таблицу разделов выскакивает снова сообщение - `“The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.”`. Windows устанавливается без каких либо проблем и отлично работает.

Если я пытаюсь установить сначала linux, то при установке вылетает ошибка - `Failed to create a file system - The efi file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI 1(0,1,0) (sda) failed`

Comment: Жёсткий диск на битые блоки проверяли?

Comment: Да, все нормально с ним. Windows 10 без проблем ставится и работает. 2 дня назад поменял материнскую плату, на старой был `bios` на новой `uefi`. На старой мп все ставилось хорошо, на новой такая проблема.

Comment: `Warning: /dev/sda: unrecognised disk lable`, вот из-за этой ошибки ничего не хочет распределяться

Comment: [Ответ на этот вопрос в другом моем вопросе.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/982988/unrecognised-disk-label-%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA/983278#983278)