# unrecognised disk label. Что я делаю не так?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gparted, fdisk

Эта ошибка - `unrecognised disk label` преследует меня уже 8-ой час. Я пытаюсь установить ubuntu, хоть как нибудь. Попытался на нескольких разных жестких дисках установить ubuntu, что на одном, что на другом одна и та же проблема, тут явно я делаю что то не так. Я загружаюсь с `liveCD` ubuntu. Если полностью освободить диск, чтобы вся его память была не распределена, то система не может сама установить ему label. Через `gdisk` пытался создать таблицу разделов(опцией w) - пишет, что успешно все создано, но только ничего не поменялось в `gparted`. Через `fdisk` пытался создать также таблицу разделов, тоже самое. Через `parted` с опцией `mklable gpt`, пишу команду, `parted` принимает ее, но эффекта опять же никакого. Как с этим бороться?

Если просто без всяких созданий разделов запустить инсталяцию убунту, то вот, что выскакивает в ответ - `the efi file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) failed`. Материнская плата с `UEFI`, на `BIOS` таких проблем ни разу не было.

Если пытаюсь через `gparted` формат раздела поменять с `ntfs` на `ext4`, такая ошибка выскакивает - `The file /dev/sda does not exist and no size was specified`

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, в вопросе подробнее, что именно Вы вводите через `gdisk`, и в другие команды тоже. И что они выводят.

Comment: Есть тег `gparted`, но ты почему-то описываешь cli. Через `gparted live` тоже диск не бьётся?

Comment: `gparted live` все руинит. Я захожу сделать разметку и разбить на разделы, и когда применяю сделанные изменения изменения, выскакивает ошибка - `unrecognised disk label` и диск полностью форматируется и `live ubuntu` не может его инициализировать больше

Comment: @SergeyNudnov, уже не буду описывать,потому что проблема не в жестких дисках и не в моих командах, их можно было вообще не использовать, проблема в материнской плате. Я вчера взял старую материнскую плату и попробовал установить линукс, все отлично встало. Это новая материнская плата не дает поставить `unix` подобные системы. Материнская плата - Gigabyte 970A ds3p rev 2.1, я почитал о ней насчет моего вопроса и да, такая проблема имеет место быть. Пока еще не разобрался, даст она вообще поставить ОС или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я победил в этом бою, боролся с `GA-970A DS3P`. Все ошибки, которые у меня возникали: `unrecognised disk label`, `gparted` не мог создать разметку диска, загрузчик `grub` "слетал". Все это делала материнская плата `GA-970A DS3P`. На этой материнской плате, вернее на чипсете 970 какие-то недопонимания с ядром `unix`-подобных систем.
В итоге, в `UEFI` есть опция `IOMMU`, по умолчанию она выключена, чтобы можно было поставить любой linux-дистрибутив с этой `МП` необходимо включить эту опцию. Ее можно потом отключить, но не заходить в `linux`, иначе словите `grub` к себе в карман и будете возиться с его восстановлением. Т.е. если ставить две ОС - `Windows` и `linux`, можно с выключенной опцией заходить в `Windows`, хотите зайти в `linux`? Включаем `IOMMU` и заходим. В некоторых случаях `IOMMU` можно выключить и забыть про нее, но у меня так не получается почему-то, постоянно приходится включать/выключать. Почему бы не оставить эту опцию включенной? [Ответ](https://www.newalive.net/102-gigabyte-ga-970a-ds3p-i-ubuntu.html).
P.S. Кстати, возможно, мне нужно включать/выключать `IOMMU` потому что `Windows` и `Ubuntu 19.04` стоят на разных жестких дисках.